# Logging with Celery throws OS Error 19: No such device

Tags: celery

I start my celery workers with

```
celery -A api --workdir=$APP_PATH beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler -f /logs/celery_cron.log --detach
```

but every once in a while I get the following error:

```
{"exc_type": "OSError", "exc_message": [19, "No such device"], "exc_module": "builtins"}
```

when I try to log some error.